# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4: dp.show and dp.change events are not fired when datepicker is inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using [the 4.17.37 of Bootstrap 3 Datepicker - eonasdan datepicker](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js)

I have an inline datepicker correctly showed and I would only the days mode, so I use the following code, but the events dp.show and dp.update are not fired.

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
}).on('dp.show dp.update', function () {
    $(".datepicker-days").find("th").eq(1).removeAttr('title')
    .css('cursor', 'default')
    .css('background', 'inherit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

**EDIT 1**

I tried also with dp.change (and show.dp, update.dp, change.dp too).

If the datepicker **is not inline** the events are fired.

**EDIT 2**

I'm using:

- jquery-1.12.3.min.js
- moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js
- moment.js/2.13.0/moment-with-locales.min.js
- bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js
- bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

**EDIT 3**

The same issue with version 4.17.42

Comment: Is the event name really `dp.show`? That is backwards, the "namespace" comes after in jquery events (`show.dp`). The plugin might name them backwards, though.

Comment: The event name is correct. See here https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/.

Comment: Does it `throw new Error("datetimepicker component should be placed within a relative positioned container")` ?   [My recreation of the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/cnjh1jvn/) did.

Comment: And [this works](https://jsfiddle.net/cnjh1jvn/1/). I'll write an answer anyway, in case another person hits the position issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `dp.show` event doesn't trigger when the widget is inline.

According to plugin documentation, the `dp.show` event is only emitted from `toggle()` or `show()` functions, but only if the widget was hidden before the call.

So my solution is a little bit dirty, but I think that it solves your problem. You can call `hide()` and `show()` functions immediately after widget initialization.

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
}).on('dp.show dp.change', function () {
    // console.log('dp.show or dp.change event');
    $(".datepicker-days").find("th").eq(1)
        .removeAttr('title')
        .css('cursor', 'default')
        .css('background', 'inherit')
        .on('click', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
 });

$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").hide();
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").show();
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/zeudzqe1/.

---

Any further improvement of this response is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dp.change ? (instead of dp.show)

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
}).on('dp.change dp.update', function () {
    $(".datepicker-days").find("th").eq(1).removeAttr('title')
    .css('cursor', 'default')
    .css('background', 'inherit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, but nothing changes. It seems to depend on the fact that the datepicker is inline.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [insists that the component is placed within a relatively positioned container](https://jsfiddle.net/cnjh1jvn/).

It [actually checks](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/4.17.37/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js#L470), and throws an error if needed:

> datetimepicker component should be placed within a relative positioned container

Uncaught errors cause it to abandon the rest of the code, by design.

[I fixed it](https://jsfiddle.net/cnjh1jvn/1/) by making the parent relatively positioned:

#### JS

```
// no changes!
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
}).on('dp.show dp.update', function () {
    $(".datepicker-days").find("th").eq(1).removeAttr('title')
    .css('cursor', 'default')
    .css('background', 'inherit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

#### CSS

```
.relatively-positioned {
  position: relative;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="relatively-positioned">
  <input id="datetimepicker">
</div>
```